# In Typescript, can a method exist only on a subclass?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, inheritance, typescript

I have an inheritance hierarchy in a typescript application that resembles the following:

```
class A {
   someProp: any;

   constructor(someObj: any){
   }
}


class B extends class A {
    constructor(someObj: any){
        super(someObj); 
    }

    public doStuff(){
        console.log("doing stuff!");
    }
}
```

In a second file, I attempt to call methods on the subclass after instantiating it like so:

```
var instanceB: A;
...
instanceB = new B(someObj);
instanceB.doStuff(); // produces error symbol cannot be resolved, it is probably located in an inaccessible module
```

So what am I doing wrong? As far as I understand prototypal inheritance in JavaScript, the method will be searched for in the hierarchy of regardless of where it is defined.

As a workaround, I've added an abstract method in the base class, and then I provide the implementation in the subclass. The problem with this is that I need to be able to swap one subclass for another depending on the application state. And to me, it seems unnecessary to define a method on the parent class that all subclasses need not implement.

Comment: You declare it as an `A`. TypeScript follows most other typed languages, if you declare it as a type, it's that type, not a subtype.

Comment: To answer your question, yes, methods can exist only in subtypes-but when your reference is to a superclass you can't reference subclass-specific functionality.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think what I'm looking for is an interface then. edit: to be able to change between types that implement that interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because `instanceB` is declared to be of type `A` and not the subtype `B`.

You can execute methods that belong to `B`, if `instanceB` is indeed an instance of `B`, by using a [type guard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx):

```
var instanceB: A;
...
instanceB = new B(someObj);
if (instanceB instanceof B) {
    instanceB.doStuff(); // no more error
}
```

Or by asserting `instanceB` to be of type `B`:

```
// no more error, but will throw an error when instanceB is not B
(instanceB as B).doStuff();
```